# Is there a way to write to the aws config file in node?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ini, aws-sdk-nodejs, aws-config

I want to load the AWS config file and edit the contents of the file.

I found [@aws-sdk/shared-ini-file-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@aws-sdk/shared-ini-file-loader), that works well to load the config file data as the JSON object.

```
import { loadSharedConfigFiles } from '@aws-sdk/shared-ini-file-loader'

let awsFileContents = await loadSharedConfigFiles({ configFilepath: '~/.aws/config' })
console.log(awsFileContents.configFile)
```

Now I want to perform some changes in the `awsFileContents.configFile` object, parse it back to the correct format, and write it back to the `~/.aws/config` file.

Is there an AWS module available that can do that?

I have tried [ini](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ini), [multi-ini](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multi-ini), and [conf-cfg-ini](https://www.npmjs.com/package/conf-cfg-ini). But they have [issues](https://github.com/npm/ini/issues/165) while parsing the JSON back to the correct format.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the SDK to read/write the config file. It is a **normal** INI file you can modify with standard tools for INI files.
You can use e.g. the ini package for this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ini

In other languages like Python and also for my "AWS Manager" (Windows application written in Delphi) I use simple ini function to read and also write the config file without any issues.

Comment: The ini module has an issue while writing to the file. It doesn't handle the value with spaces well which leads to the failure of the AWS CLI commands. I added the link to the issue in the description.

Comment: @ShishirAnshuman damn... than this is really related to Javascript... normally this should work without any issues... maybe someone can provide a usable library for this or can fix this behaviour in this library as soon as possible -> https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-ini?